# Select substring after specific word

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, regex, string

From strings like this

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KRFHiBW9RE8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I need to select only the source, so the word between src="the string I need"

I have tried using IndexOf the word src=" but the link doesn't have a fixed number of characters to set the ending.

Comment: you should also search for " after you found src="

Comment: You must do this on server side? If so don't use magic strings, consider to use HTMLAgilityPack

Comment: Do you have control over this iframe ? I mean you will add this or this will be added from somewhere else ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're trying to parse some HTML code - it might be better to use [HTMLAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex).

But in the case it is just some set of strings you've obtained from somewhere and want to parse - you can also do it using [regular expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string s ="<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/KRFHiBW9RE8\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
var match = Regex.Match(s, "src=\"(.*?)\"");
string src;
if (match.Success)
    src = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 4):

A naive implementation, in which I assume you have a string as input:

```
string input = "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/KRFHiBW9RE8\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

if (input.Contains("src=\""))
{
    string output = input.Substring(input.IndexOf("src=\"") + 5);
    // output is: https://www.youtube.com/embed/KRFHiBW9RE8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    output = output.Substring(0, output.IndexOf("\""));
    // output is: https://www.youtube.com/embed/KRFHiBW9RE8
}
```

It will certainly miss edge cases like `src ="`, but will give you a place to start. Obviously this is also a problem which can be solved using regular expressions; I'll leave that for someone else to answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be tempted to split all the properties out into an array as it's possible I might want some of the others later on as well. In doing this it would also allow easy access to the 'src' property. So I'd do something like this:

```
string iFrameString = "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/KRFHiBW9RE8\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen>";

//split properties based on spaces
string[] tagProps = iFrameString.Split(new Char[]{' '});

//get the property out.
string prop = "src=\"";
string source = Array.Find(tagProps, x => x.StartsWith(prop, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

string ModifiedSource = source.Substring(prop.Length,source.Length - prop.Length);
```

The benefit of this is that you have all the other properties in your array as well and you could get those out if needed.